# Loading from gallery pushes app into status bar ionic ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic5

screenshots are posted in order
so webview works fine and does not mix in with the status bar in any way, its only until I try to upload an image from the gallery that it pushes the app into the status bar (see order of picture for an example)

i have added `this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false)` and tried `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />` but it breaks as soon as the photo selection takes place[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzUaJ.png)

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzUaJ.png)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPdLJ.png)

[3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Wf1.png)

[4th image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cSdl.png)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I used ion-header instead of ion-toolbar